# Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 WordPress REST Api – Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

We are building a mobile app which make use of contents resides on our WordPress site.
On the developer console we already set our redirect url to http://localhost/WordPressTester/testRestpage.php and website to http://localhost/
This work well and redirects us back to the localhost/ WordPressTester /testRestpage.php.
We have follow this instruction using the code below:

```
<?php 
$ClientId="xxxxx";
$ClientSecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$redirectUrl="http://localhost/WordPressTester/testRestpage.php";
$authUrl="https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=".$ClientId."&redirect_uri=".$redirectUrl."&response_type=code&blog=http://oursite.com";
//==============================
// Work Now
//=============
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
$curl = curl_init( 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'client_id' => $ClientId,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl,
    'client_secret' =>$ClientSecret,
    'code' => $_GET['code'], // The code from the previous request
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$auth = curl_exec( $curl );
$secret = json_decode($auth , true);
$access_key = $secret->access_token;
echo "Here is the Token<br/>".$access_key;
}
else
{
    echo "<a href='".$authUrl."' >Authorise App</a>";
}
?>
```

However, after redirect we got this error message. Instead of producing the access_token

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\TechLocal\WordPressTester\ testRestpage.php
on line 19**

We know that there is Plugin out there to use instead of these but we will like to follow the instruction on wordpress.com
Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution, it was because  I was running the code on local server.

I moved the application to live site and it work fine.

I also find out about these two useful links

1. [WordPress-Android](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android)
2. [WordPress-iOS](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS)